# WCF Throttling , InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode

Tags: wcf, throttling

Which ConcurrencyMode and InstanceContextMode combination is best for WCF REST services considering heavy load?

Comment: InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode.Single or Reentrant (depending on if you're making another wcf call from your service)